# No suitable constructor found 1.18 java mod

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I’m mid-way though writing a Minecraft 1.18.2 mod (Forge 40.1.80).
As this is the first Minecraft mod I am writing, I’m not too experienced in the field and have no idea what is causing this issue. When I try running the code I get this error (4 times): java: no suitable constructor found for Block(net.minecraft.world.level.block.state.BlockBehaviour.Properties). Any help would be greatly appreciated. The error appears here: "() -> new Block(ORE_PROPERTIES <-Here"

```
package com.example.factorytechv0_1.startup;

import net.minecraft.resources.ResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.world.item.BlockItem;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.state.BlockBehaviour;
import net.minecraft.world.level.material.Material;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.IEventBus;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLJavaModLoadingContext;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.RegistryObject;
import org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.ir.Block;

public class Registration {
    private static final DeferredRegister<Block> BLOCKS = DeferredRegister.create((ResourceLocation) ForgeRegistries.BLOCKS, "factorytechv0_1");
    private static final DeferredRegister<Item> ITEMS = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.ITEMS, "factorytechv0_1");
    public static void init() {
        IEventBus bus = FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus();
        BLOCKS.register(FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus());
        ITEMS.register(FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus());
    }

    public static final BlockBehaviour.Properties ORE_PROPERTIES = BlockBehaviour.Properties.of(Material.STONE).strength(2f);
    public static final Item.Properties ITEM_PROPERTIES = new Item.Properties().tab(ModSetup.ITEM_GROUP);
    public static final RegistryObject<Block> CHROME_ORE_OVERWORLD = BLOCKS.register("chrome_ore_overworld", () -> new Block(ORE_PROPERTIES));
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> CHROME_ORE_OVERWORLD_ITEM = fromBlock(CHROME_ORE_OVERWORLD);
    public static final RegistryObject<Block> CHROME_ORE_DEEPSLATE = BLOCKS.register("chrome_ore_deepslate", () -> new Block(ORE_PROPERTIES));
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> CHROME_ORE_DEEPSLATE_ITEM = fromBlock(CHROME_ORE_DEEPSLATE);
    public static final RegistryObject<Block> HAFNIUM_ORE_NETHER = BLOCKS.register("hafnium_ore_nether", () -> new Block(ORE_PROPERTIES));
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> HAFNIUM_ORE_NETHER_ITEM = fromBlock(HAFNIUM_ORE_NETHER);
    public static final RegistryObject<Block> TECHNETIUM_ORE_END = BLOCKS.register("technetium_ore_end", () -> new Block(ORE_PROPERTIES));
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> TECHNETIUM_ORE_END_ITEM = fromBlock(TECHNETIUM_ORE_END);

    public static <B extends Block> RegistryObject<Item> fromBlock(RegistryObject<B> block)
    {
        return ITEMS.register(block.getId().getPath(), () -> new BlockItem(block.get(), ITEM_PROPERTIES));
    }
}
```

Here is the main initialisation file for the mod (if needed)

```
package com.example.factorytechv0_1;

import com.example.factorytechv0_1.startup.ClientSetup;
import com.example.factorytechv0_1.startup.ModSetup;
import com.example.factorytechv0_1.startup.Registration;
import com.mojang.logging.LogUtils;
import net.minecraftforge.api.distmarker.Dist;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.IEventBus;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.DistExecutor;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLJavaModLoadingContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

// The value here should match an entry in the META-INF/mods.toml file
@Mod("factorytechv0_1")
public class factorytechv0_1 {

    // Directly reference a slf4j logger
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogUtils.getLogger();

    public factorytechv0_1() {

        // Register the deferred reg
        Registration.init();

        // Register the setup method for Modloading
        IEventBus modbus = FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus();
        modbus.addListener(ModSetup::init);
        DistExecutor.unsafeRunWhenOn(Dist.CLIENT, () -> () -> modbus.addListener(ClientSetup::init));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might have the wrong import, perhaps intellij/eclipse suggested the wrong one for you.

```
import org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.ir.Block
```

This import looks weird, please remove it and replace it with something starting with `net.minecraft.world.item`.

Comment: isn't it `net.minecraft.world.block.Block`?

Answer (score -2):

Had a fast look at the API 1.18.2 , the class is abstract.

**Here there is a little bit more to it, this shows how
https://moddingtutorials.org/o19/basic-blocks**
**What it is occurs when calling a new instance is  BlockBehaviour.Properties is static but assigning it to the constructor argument instantly makes it an instance reference "no longer static" but it's methods are static,  to overcome that, during construction the .of() method is called by that syntax notation and the properties are set "of the class" while the static state is being assigned to the constructor argument, in the hierarchy is a BlockBehaviour.Properties and is the copy of that instance available(for lack of better expression because it's static and only one copy).
After it is passed into the constructor, all the higher classes it extends have a constructor argument must be passed into as BlockBehaviour.Properties type so the first line in your customised class will have super(theblockpropargref); the theblockpropargref variable is now an instance and not static.
The looney point is the .of() method is called attached to the new instance customised class call but the BlockBehaviour.Properties is a class in the hierarchy of the new customised class so it searches it's own hierarchy for the .of()  method signature and argument loading and finds it in it's own "static class" BlockBehaviour.Properties , the actual mad point is it must become an instance but must be called with a method to exist , but to not return a value from a method it must use a "void" method or be returning the type the instance variable is so it can only be assigned and exist during calling it before being made an instance of its type to be put on an instance variable teference**

If you look at class Block it's used to "extend from" as normally an abstract class is used.
Now take a look at the API docs for Block class and near the top of page you can find "what that point is for" from the "list of known sub classes"
https://nekoyue.github.io/ForgeJavaDocs-NG/javadoc/1.18.2/net/minecraft/world/level/block/Block.html

Those are all bits and pieces that have unique properties and behaviours.

And at the bottom of the hierarchy where a class can be instantiated "new" here is an example API docs
https://nekoyue.github.io/ForgeJavaDocs-NG/javadoc/1.18.2/net/minecraft/world/level/block/DetectorRailBlock.html

There should be somewhere some proper Minecraft tutorial.

If you ever did make a new one you would extend from it to make a new one or cast type dependent if suitable.
It seems to be an enclosing static class wrapper but it has methods in its own level. However, it does contain static classes and those are simply called with their method to use , not instantiated new.